# Pandas Group by TimeGrouper

Tags: python, pandas

I want to group my data by month selecting the last row of each month.

Data:

```
>>> df
Date
1985-10-14    46.50
1985-10-23    47.50
1985-10-24    46.88
1985-11-21    50.25
1985-11-22    50.38
1985-11-25    50.38
>>> df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('M')).nth(-1)
Date
1985-10-31    46.88
1985-11-30    50.38
```

Expected Result:

```
1985-10-24    46.88
1985-11-25    50.38
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need first create column from `DatetimeIndex` by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and then use [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with [`Resampler.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.last.html), last remove `index`:

```
print (df)
              col
Date             
1985-10-14  46.50
1985-10-23  47.50
1985-10-24  46.88
1985-11-21  50.25
1985-11-22  50.38
1985-11-25  50.38


df = df.reset_index().resample('M', on='Date').last().reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
        Date    col
0 1985-10-24  46.88
1 1985-11-25  50.38
```

For oldier versions create column from index:

```
df = df.assign(Date=df.index).resample('M').last().reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
     col       Date
0  46.88 1985-10-24
1  50.38 1985-11-25
```

---

```
df['Date'] = df.index
df = df.resample('M').last().reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
     col       Date
0  46.88 1985-10-24
1  50.38 1985-11-25
```

Comment: on parameter in resample is in 0.19 version of pandas
what if i m using 0.18